# Socket programming for mobile phones in Python

Tags: python, sockets, mobile

I've written code for communication between my phone and comp thru TCP sockets. When I type out the code line by line in the interactive console it works fine. However, when i try running the script directly through filebrowser.py it just wont work. I'm using Nokia N95. Is there anyway I can run this script directly without using filebrowser.py?

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [Hack a Mobile Phone with Linux and Python](http://pramode.net/articles/lfy/mobile/pramode.html)? It is rather old, but maybe you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is working in the interactive interpreter when typed, but not when run directly then I would suggest seeing if your code has reached a deadlock on the socket, for example both ends are waiting for data from the other.  When typing into the interactive interpreter there is a longer delay between the execution of each line on code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it doesn't appear to be a deadlock situation. It throws an error saying remote server refused connection. However, like I said before, if i type the very same code into the interactive interpreter it works just fine. I'm wondering if the error is because the script is run through filebrowser.py?

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have the "Run script" menu in your interactive Python shell?